# Detecting if a child component has a specific mixin/method in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my component's render method, I need to filter through the `props.children` variable looking for components that have a specific method or property, but I'm unable to expose any methods or properties on the children. I'd like to have the method be inherited from a mixin.

Example:

```
var barMixin = {
    isBar: function() { return true; }
};

var Foo = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var filteredChildren = this.props.children.filter(function(child) {
            return child.isBar();
        });
        return (
            <div>
                {filteredChildren}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, this example doesn't work because `child.isBar` is `undefined` even when the child components inherit the mixin `barMixin`.

Is there something I'm misunderstanding? I've also tried declaring my mixin methods as static like this:

```
var barMixin = {
    statics: {
        isBar: function() { return true; }
    }
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

I've found a working solution:

```
var barMixin = {
    getDefaultProps: function() {
        return {
            isBar: function() { return true; }
        };
    }
};
```

Checking in the render function with: `child.props.isBar()`. However, this doesn't seem like the correct way to do this.

Comment: Why create a function `isBar()` instead of just `isBar: true` ?

Comment: I think you're looking at it from a wrong perspective (just a guess). Look at the state of the parent to decide if the children should be rendered.

Comment: Yeah you shouldn't be doing this.  Pass props from parent to child to determine how the child should render, or make the parent decide which component to render etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a small library to deal with the Children structure that may be handy for your problem. You can deal even with deep children if you need. You can get it here: https://github.com/fernandopasik/react-children-utilities.

```
import React from 'react';
import Children from 'react-children-utilities';

function isBar(child) { return true; }

function Foo(props) {
    return <div>{Children(this.props.children).filter(isBar)}</div>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** If your problem is according to access the mixin from children, then don't read, i possibly misread your question :( Otherwise, some things about mixins lower...

You should stick to the original form of using a mixin. I think, the best use-case to use a mixin is code sharing. So i assume, you are using some module system in your code, to require the mixin. If so, you can use it like:

```
var Foo = React.createClass({
    mixins: [fooMixin],
    render: function() {
        console.log(this.isBar()); // using the mixin
        return (
            <div>
                Something
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

I've created a sample to demonstrate the usage.

```js
define('fooMixin', {

  isBar: function() {
    return 'Something';
  }

});


require(['fooMixin'], function(fooMixin) {

  var Foo = React.createClass({

    mixins: [fooMixin],

    render: function() {
      
      var div = React.createFactory('div');

      return div(null, this.isBar());

    }
  });

  React.render(Foo(), document.getElementById('content'));

});
```

```html
<script src="http://fb.me/react-with-addons-0.12.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.15/require.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Also the sample can be seen on JSFiddle with JSX -> http://jsfiddle.net/8hby56sa/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this doesn't answer the question.